# Moving Adaptive Payments App from sandbox to live - Transaction is Invalid

Tags: php, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm moving an app from sandbox to live. I've changed to my live api user, api signature, api password and appid.

In addition I modified the api url and paypal url as follows.

```
`//public $apiUrl = 'https://svcs. sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/';`
`//public $paypalUrl = "https://www. sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=";    `

`public $apiUrl = 'https://svcs. paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/'; `
`public $paypalUrl = "https://www. paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=";`
```

I'm landing on payal at 
    `"url https://www .paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey="`
with no paykey populated.

I'm getting a message on the paypal page that says "This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website and try again."

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a trillion in advance for your help.